# Probability Question Replaced and Not Replaced

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are 3 blue balls, 3 Green balls, and 6 Red balls.(R 6 , B 3 , G 3)

We take two balls one after another.

If the first ball is red , we replace the red ball and add another red and a blue.(R 7 , B 4 , G 3) Then take the second ball.

If the first ball is green , we replace the green ball and add another red and a blue.(R 7 , B 4 , G 3) Then take the second ball.

If the first ball is blue, we do not replace.(R 6 , B 2 , G 3) Then take the second ball.

1) What is the probability of getting a blue ball in the second take?

2) What is the probability of getting a blue ball first, if it is given that the second ball is blue?

My Attempt :

**Case I**

Prob of getting a red or green ball first is $\frac{6+3}{6+3+3}=\frac{9}{12}$

Then Prob of getting a blue ball the second time is $\frac{4}{7+4+3}=\frac{4}{14}$

**Case II**

Prob of getting a blue ball first is $\frac{3}{12}$

Then Prob of getting a blue ball the second time is $\frac{2}{6+2+3}=\frac{2}{11}$

any help after this ?

Comment: The sentence "If the first ball is red or green, we replace the red ball with another red and a blue" makes sense if a red ball is selected first, but you cannot replace the red ball you select if you have selected a green ball.  Please clarify.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: You didn't resolve the comment by @N.F.Taussig I don't think.  What do you do if the first ball is green?  There is then no red ball to replace.  I think it will be clearer if you break this into two situations.  "If the first ball is red, we replace the red ball with another red and a blue.  If the first ball is green, we ... "

Comment: either Red or green ! Im sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the probability of getting a blue ball on the second take?

Let $Pr(B)$, $Pr(G)$, and $Pr(R)$ denote, respectively, the probabilities of obtaining a blue ball, green ball, and a red ball.

Let $Pr(B \mid B)$, $\Pr(B \mid G)$, $\Pr(B \mid R)$ denote, respectively, the probabilities of obtaining a blue ball given that a blue, green, or red ball was selected.

Observe that 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(B) & = \frac{3}{12}\\
\Pr(G) & = \frac{3}{12}\\
\Pr(R) & = \frac{6}{12}\\
\Pr(B \mid B) & = \frac{3 - 1}{12 - 1} = \frac{2}{11}\\
\Pr(B \mid G) & = \frac{3 + 1}{12 + 1 + 1} = \frac{4}{14}\\
\Pr(B \mid R) & = \frac{3 + 1}{12 + 1 + 1} = \frac{4}{14}
\end{align*}

The probability that a blue ball is obtained on the second take is 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\text{blue ball on second take}) & = \Pr(B)\Pr(B \mid B) + \Pr(B)\Pr(B \mid G) + \Pr(B \mid R)\\
& = \frac{2}{11} \cdot \frac{3}{12} + \frac{4}{14} \cdot \frac{3}{12} + \frac{4}{14} \cdot \frac{6}{12}
\end{align*}

> What is the probability that the first ball was blue given that a blue ball was obtained on the second take.

We must divide the probability that a blue ball was obtained on both the first and second take by the probability that a blue ball was taken on the second take.

$$\Pr(\text{first ball was blue} \mid \text{second ball was blue}) = \frac{\Pr(B)Pr(B \mid B)}{\Pr(B)\Pr(B \mid B) + \Pr(B)\Pr(B \mid G) + \Pr(B \mid R)}$$
which I will leave to you to compute.

Comment: Thank you very much.